# changing countries in t:selectOneCountry

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

I am using t:selectOneCountry to show a country list with JSF 1.2. My quesion has two parts:

1. Can I filter a specific country from the list?
2. Can I change the title of a country (to show a more complete title)?

I have saw:
http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_selectOneCountry.html and it has mentioned using f:select filters but I can't figure out exactly what code I must write.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly you can use `<f:selectItem>` tags to restrict the country list to some countries. Something like:

```
<t:selectOneCountry ....>
  <f:selectItem value="DE"/>
  <f:selectItem value="UK"/>
  <f:selectItem value="FR"/>
</t:selectOneCountry>
```